# tomcat server not functioning properly

Tags: tomcat, server

Today I completely worked with tomcat, creating HTML pages, and servlets, it worked and did not give me any trouble. but now suddenly when I wanted to open my pages using tomcat, the browser is showing the following error.

> This localhost page can’t be found
>   No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:1996/cart.html
>   Search Google for localhost 1996 cart HTTP ERROR 404

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: There's nothing here anybody can use to help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please start at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and edit your question